# Youtube live chat box is not display properly in iframe

Tags: javascript, css, youtube, youtube-livestreaming-api

I am trying to add chat box in website. Chatbox of youtube live chat is not display properly.
Here is my jsfiddle link

https://jsfiddle.net/webregister/wnbz0edo/15/

If you found chat is not running.Please take new youtube id from any youtube live stream using youtube share option. Replace  YOUTUBE-ID within your Id inside iframe src url

```
 <iframe  src="https://www.youtube.com/live_chat?v=YOUTUBE-ID&embed_domain=fiddle.jshell.net" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a height on the iframe container:

```
.pop-iframe-container {
  height: 100%;
}
```

Working fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/kmturley/4Lxu6kvd/1/